# How can I print a numbered list using elements from another list?

Tags: python

I am trying to generate and print a numbered list using items from this list:

ItemList = [Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4]

So, the numbered list should look like this.

1. Item1
2. Item2
3. Item3
4. Item4

Then the program will ask for the user to choose an item. The user will choose an item by inputting a number 1 through 4.

The program should then assign the user's chosen item to a variable, let's call it UserChoice.

I've tried many different approaches by assigning the user's input to an index of a list, but it's not working.

```
Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4 = "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"

ItemList = [Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4]
```

## Here I am not sure how to print the actual index of each item.

```py
OptionsList = for x in ItemList:
                 print(x)

userInput = input("Choose an item by inputting a number 1-4.")

List.index = userInput

UserChoice = List.index

print(UserChoice)
```

I expect the item from the list the user selects by inputting a number 1-4 to be assigned to the userchoice variable.

For the record, the item lists will vary in size, so it could not be code which only provisions for 1-4. It could be 1-8, 1-3, 1-5. It could be a variety of ranges.

Comment: Please format the code: select it and type `ctrl-k`.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting ... https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: See [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `enumerate` to print the indexes of the items. Then, take user input, subtract one because lists are zero-indexed, and use it access the chosen element.

```
ItemList = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']

for index, item in enumerate(ItemList, start=1):
    print(index, item)

input_index = int(input('Choose an item by inputting a number 1-{}.\n'.format(len(ItemList))))
user_choice = ItemList[input_index - 1]
print('You chose:', user_choice)
```

Comment: awesome! thank you so much!

Comment: @SimonCrawford No problem. Also, I changed it so it prints out the indexes starting from 1.

Comment: @Timothy32 I also added the "\b." to put a decimal after the number.

Comment: @Timothy32, how come I have to put int before input? I don't see this anywhere in the documents of python. It WORKS. I'm just curious why regular input doesn't work.

Comment: @SimonCrawford The index of a list must be an integer. `input` returns a string. Plus, we can't subtract 1 from a string. We have to convert into an integer first.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Define menu items
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
    'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
# Define format for each line of the menu (indentation of the numbers)
line = "{{: >{}}}. {{}}".format(len(str(len(items))))
# Loop to print all items and their respective number
for i, item in enumerate(items, 1):
    print(line.format(i, item))
# Input from user
number = int(input("Please choose a number: "))
# Print chosen item back to user
print("You have selected: {}".format(items[number - 1]))
```

This solution essentially uses a loop with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) for each line. Your output might look like this:

```
 1. a
 2. b
 3. c
 4. d
 5. e
 6. f
 7. g
 8. h
 9. i
10. j
11. k
12. l
13. m
14. n
15. o
16. p
17. q
18. r
19. s
20. t
21. u
22. v
23. w
24. x
25. y
26. z
Please choose a number: 22
You have selected: v
```

You'll still have to work on some things like faulty user input like a negative number or not a number at all.

Comment: i thank you for help

Comment: See [**`string.ascii_lowercase`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase)